# how to get value entered in function

Tags: c, function

I need to multiply two matrices with three functions: load, multiply and write. Example says not to use pointers or structures and I'm very confused because I can't get value of number of rows and columns of each matrix.

```
void load(int [][10], int, int);
void write(int [][10], int, int);
void multiply(int [][10], int [][10], int [][10], int, int, int, int);

int main(){
    int n, m, x, y, a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10];
    printf("First:\n");
    load(a, n, m);
    printf("Second:\n");
    load(b, x, y);
    if (m != x)
    printf("Can't multiply");
    else{
        multiply(a, b, c, n, m, x, y);
        write(c, n, y);
    }

    return 0;
}

void load(int a[][10], int n, int m){
    printf("Rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        } 
}
```

So, how do I save values into n, m, x, y?

Comment: By the unwise practice of making them global. Or by having them in an array too: `int dims[4];` or int `dima[2], dimb[2];`

Comment: but this is already using pointer `load(b, x, y);` if you cannot use pointers then global is the only way at least i know of

Comment: The input of `"Rows and columns: "` should be made outside/before calling the function `load`, so that the values of `n` and `m` can be passed as parameters of the function `load`. And so that you have these values in the scope of the `main` function to be used with the other functions as well.